# Python can't print as a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print a section of lines from a file but print only results in an empty set of brakcets [], How can I print file_data as a string.

```
file_data=(file.readlines()[(array1):(array2)])
print(file_data)
```

EDIT: Sorry guys the complete code is here it is just a program to communicate thorugh ssh

```
import sys
import threading 
import paramiko
import socket

host_key=paramiko.RSAKey(filename='/home/jack/.ssh/id_rsa')

class Server(paramiko.ServerInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        self.event=threading.Event()
    def check_channel_request(self,kind,chanid):
        if kind == 'session':
            return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED
        return paramiko.OPEN_FAILED_ADMINISTRATIVELY_PROHIBITED
    def check_auth_password(self,username,password):
        if (username=='root') and (password=='toor'):
            return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
        return paramiko.AUTH_FAILED
try: 
    sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(('192.168.1.7', 1258))
    sock.listen(100)
    print('[+] Listening for connection....')
    client, addr=sock.accept()
except Exception as e:
    print('[-] Listen/bind/accept failed')
    sys.exit(1)
print('[+] Connection Initiated')

try:
    transport=paramiko.Transport(client)
    try:
        transport.load_server_moduli()
    except:
        print('[-] Failed to load moduli -- gex will be unsupported')
        raise
    transport.add_server_key(host_key)
    server=Server()
    try:
        transport.start_server(server=server)
    except:
        paramiko.SSHException()
        print('[-] SSH negotiation failed')
    chan=transport.accept(20)
    print('[+] Authentication Completed')
    returned=(chan.recv(1024))
    print(returned.decode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict'))
    chan.send("Connection established")
    while True:
        command=input('Enter Command=>').strip('\n')
        if command=='exit':
            transport.close()
            sys.exit(1)
        if command=='File_Transfer-SF':
            file_location=input('Enter File Location=>')
            file_destination=input('Enter File Destination=>')
            packet=('File_Transfer-SF-'+file_destination)
            chan.send(packet)
            chan.recv(1) 
            file=open(file_location,'r+')
            file_length=len(file.readlines())
            array1=-8
            array2=0
            print('A')
            while array2 != (file_length+1):
                array1=array1+8
                array2=array2+8
                if array2>=(file_length+1):
                    array2==(file_length+1)
                print('B')
                file_data=(file.readlines()[(array1):(array2)])
                print(print("\n".join(file_data)))
                chan.send(file_data)
                print('C')
                chan.recv(1)
                if array2==(file_length+1):
                    chan.send('**COMPLETE**')
        else:
            chan.send(command)
            print('C')
            print(chan.recv(2048).decode('UTF-8'))
except Exception as e:
    print('[-] Exception'+': ' + str(e))
    try:
       transport.close()
    except:
        pass
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Please post complete example code in your question, along with expected output etc.

Comment: What's the content of your file? what's array1, array2? what do you expect to be printed?

Comment: I have no idea what are `array1` and `array2`, but if `file_data` shows up as `[]` I **can** tell you confidently that either `file` has no lines at all, or else `array1 >= array2` (assuming for simplicity that they're positive).

Comment: What is `print(print("\n".join(file_data)))` supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry about them, they are just numbers im using to define the range of the array (file.readlines()[(array1):(array2)]), I think you may be right about the empty file, I am going to make sure the right file is being accessed Edit: Nevermind the file is not empty and is being accessed

Comment: @ Klaus D. I was trying to use the solution posted by juniorCompressor I accdentally typed print twice however after fixing the issue it still didnt work

Comment: after further work i figured out The file isnt properly being read, it is reading the file as if it is empty, sorry about the confusion i think I will delete this post because of how confusing I made it, very sorry guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `file_length=len(file.readlines())` you read the file's content completely, and later you assume you can read it again...this won't work, the file will seem to be empty. You can reset the filepointer with the `seek(0)` command, or close and reopen it.
Personally, I would not use a python keyword as a name for a variable, like `file` (`file` is a synonym of `open`). Just use 'infile' or such.